# git push failed with error object hasDotgit: contains '.git'

Tags: git, git-push

I wanted to push a git repo to a self hosted gitlab server, and I got the following error:

```
# git push -u origin --all --no-thin
Enumerating objects: 854410, done.
Counting objects: 100% (854410/854410), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (209251/209251), done.
remote: error: object 57364fe6ff4138ec58762676f24a581f5810025a: hasDotgit: contains '.git'
remote: fatal: fsck error in packed object
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

Use `git show` to check the object `57364fe6ff4138ec58762676f24a581f5810025a`, I got following output:

```
# git show 57364fe6ff4138ec58762676f24a581f5810025a
tree 57364fe6ff4138ec58762676f24a581f5810025a      
                                               
.clang-format                                      
.editorconfig                                      
.git/                                              
.gitignore                                         
.style.yapf                                        
AUTHORS                                            
LICENSE                                            
OWNERS                                             
README.md                                          
base/                                              
build/                                             
docs/                                              
infra/                                             
out/                                               
tools/                                             
util/
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this situation? This is a repo maintained by a team which has thousands of commit after this commit. I can't do git reset on it.
I think some expert tools like "git filter-repo" or "git filter-branch" maybe can help me, but I don't know how use them.

Comment: It's not valid for a Git repository to contain a directory or file named `.git`, and modern Git refuses to work with such a repository. This is a security precaution: a repository that contains `.git` could be a Trojan horse, of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the commits that contain a `.git` directory, and edit them.

---

Finding the commits :

A starting point is to find the `.git` directories in your current working directory, then list all commits that modified this directory :

```
# from your directory root :
find . -name .git -type f

# if you find directories other than the root .git directory :
git log --oneline --graph -- path/to/.git
```

---

Editing the commits :

Basically : if you find a rogue `.git` folder which has been versioned in your repo, you need to call `git rm --cached path/to/.git` on the commits that contain it.

- If this rogue .git directory appeared in your last commit only :

  ```
  git rm --cached path/to/.git
  git commit --amend
  ```
- If you see a handful of commits in the git log command above : use `git rebase -i`, set the target commits to "edit", and remove the fawlty directory
- You can also use a systematic rewriting tool, such as `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo`

  ```
  git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached path/to/.git' --all
  ```

Comment: This is a repo maintained by a team which has thousands of commit behind. please tell me more about `git filter-repo` and `git filter-branch`

Comment: @Gavin : you will also need to `push --force`. If it is a very shared repo, you will also have to tell the teams to sync their local copy, and inform them to make sure the accidental `.git` folder does not reappear again.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the start point is find out the path of the .git. Because the .git was already deleted by some commit. that's spend me a lot of time.

Comment: Since git filter-branch (on windows) reports "has a lot of gotchas" and it recommends git filter-repo, would be nice to see an analog to the filter-branch statement above using git filter-repo

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your error with these few commands:

```
git reset --soft 57364fe6ff4138ec58762676f24a581f5810025a #delete all commits after the last good one (5736), but keep files (--soft)

git rm --cached "." -r -f #git rm all files but keep them locally (--cached)

git add . #git add everything back

git commit -m "commit message"
```

Comment: Watch it : if the OP's history has other commits on top of the failing one, your answer will squash all commits into one single commit.

Comment: This is a git repo maintained by a team which has thousands of commit after this broken commit. I can't do the git reset on it.